# JQM flip switch rendering issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, rendering, switch-statement, flip

I am using a JQM flip switch in one of my views in an ASP.Net MVC 4 mobile web application.  When the flip switch is moved all the way to the right it is showing an unwanted vertical line when rendering.  See screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.Label("AutoLogin", New With {.style = "text-align:center;font-weight:bold"})
       <div class="center-wrapper">
        <select name="AutoLogin" id="AutoLogin" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
          <option value ="false">Off</option>
          <option value ="true">On</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

center-wrapper class:

```
 .center-wrapper{
 text-align: center;
 }
.center-wrapper * {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

EDIT:

I discovered that this rendering issue is not caused by centering the flip switch but is instead caused by simply having the flip switch inside of a list item.  If I reduce the flip switch down to its simplest form (see below), I still get the rendering issue if the flip switch is inside of a list item.  You should be able to easily reproduce this.

```
<label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
  <option value="off">Off</option>
  <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

Comment: center-wrapper class is your probable problem. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: center-wrapper class added to question as requested.

Comment: Can anyone help with this??